# how many times enter wrong words in recaptcha in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, captcha

I am using google ReCAPTCHA in my ASP.NET MVC Project, Now I want to count how many times a person enter wrong words or how many times he tried

Please help me

Comment: How are you submitting the form? are you using ajax or html? Can you post some of the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation would be store the value in a cookie.

(cshtml / razor)

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Captcha</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Captcha", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    @Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey: "...")    
    <input type="submit" value="validate"/>
}
```

(controller)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Captcha = 0;
    return View();
}


public ActionResult Captcha()
    {
        var valid = Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "...");
        if (valid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            int failValue = 0;
            var failCookie = Request.Cookies["failCount"];

            if (failCookie == null)
            {
                failValue = 1;
                failCookie = new HttpCookie("failCount");
                failCookie.Value = failValue.ToString();
                Response.Cookies.Add(failCookie);
            }
            else
            {
                failValue = int.Parse(failCookie.Value);
                failValue = failValue + 1;
                failCookie.Value = failValue.ToString();
            }

            ViewBag.Captcha = "Failed " + failValue + " times";
            return View("Index");
        }           
    }
```